# Как в Azure настроить обработку ошибки 404 для статического сайта?

Tags: asp.net, azure

В Azure создал проект Web App но основе "HTML5 Empty Web App" для статического сайта.
Через Git загрузил файлы html.

Как теперь настроить обработку ошибки 404, т.е. чтобы отображалась подготовленная страница 404.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При работе со статическим файлом ошибки (например, 404.html) надо добавить файл конфигурации ASP.NET приложения:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="File" path="404.html" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Эксперимент показал, что возвращается код ошибки - 404.

Обратите внимание, в `path` указывается путь файловой системы.